# How to add framework to xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, frameworks

I am new to `Xcode` and want to add and use `framework` which I have taken from internet but
  when I add it to *my products folder* by *right clicking* on products and using add new files it
  runs fine and when i use my project's project.app file on my mac or on any other mac it
  gives me `dyld error` that the bundle image not find.  And when I use bundle image in my 
  `framework` folder its give me `ld error` that bundle not found help please.

```
ld: framework not found SMS-Bundled
 Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

*updated

when i add my framework to framework folder now its giving me error at run time...

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SMS-Bundled.framework/Versions/A/SMS-Bundled
  Referenced from: /Users/usman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serial_Tools-detoutxzbnjrngcuulrbgcasxmjs/Build/Products/Debug/Serial Tools.app/Contents/MacOS/Serial Tools
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Have you checked against copy resource into bundle when you added ?

Comment: what means please explain what are u saying sory i know this is silly question may b but i am new

Comment: this happens because this framework is not properly exported. You should manually Copy paste it inside your projects folder, then drag it from there. Then make sure the framework path in the project settings are set to relative within the project folder.

Comment: you means drag and then drop to framework folder??

Comment: i have drag and drop it to framework folder but now its giving dyld error that image not found error which i have updated in my question

Comment: just simple solution our here Xcode open then any project "Framework" drag and drop framework or clicl project name display "general " button click button line display add framework and set any framework. i think question answer .  any other issue please share me and me also learner so may mistake generate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In Finder)

Go to the folder where your custom framework is. copy the framework. Now go to your project's folder. Create a new folder called Frameworks, paste the custom framework inside this folder.

(In Xcode)

Drag the custom folder FROM finder to the Frameworks folder on the project explorer (where all the rest of the frameworks are)

Now select your project, go to Build Settings, scroll down to "Framework Search Paths" field, double click the value to open it, press the + to add a new path, write ./Frameworks as the new path.

From now on if you want to add other private/custom frameworks all you have to do is copy them into the created frameworks folder, and simply drag and drop it into the xcode frameworks folder. (You must drag it from the project framework folder in finder to the framework folder in xcode).

PD: You don't necessarily have to name this folder frameworks, it can be whatever, just make sure to change the Framework Search Paths accordingly.

Comment: its still giving me this runtime error:  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/SMS-Bundled.framework/Versions/A/SMS-Bundled
  Referenced from: /Users/usman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Serial_Tools-bnlbjumhuhbrhhbdeqsmfslolvil/Build/Products/Debug/Serial Tools.app/Contents/MacOS/Serial Tools
  Reason: image not found

Answer (score 0):

In your project build setting, under "framework search paths" mention the path of the framework.

This will resolve your issue.